# GitHub accounts and repositories

Tags: github

I'm new to GitHub and am wondering if I should create separate accounts / repositories.

I want to create an open source library. Being open source, it should allow for strangers to contribute in future (Let's ignore the fact that this is a very unlikely scenario). My worry is that creating a repository under my personal account may turn away strangers as they may feel that their contribution is not towards something personal. In addition, I want to cater to the possibility that I may no longer want to be associated with the repo anymore.

I also have a business name that I would like to use to create a private repository that will be using the above library. The repos will not even be published to github initially but if the projects fails then I will open source them to github. Basically, the name will be reserved and inactive for some time.

I know GitHub does not allow inactive accounts So, is there an alternative to needing the following:

- one personal account with no repos
- one organization account with one repo for that library
- one organization account with no repos initially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some suggestions @kylie

**Option 1**

Make the repo on your personal GitHub account and then private it. When you are ready to allow others to contribute to your library, just make it public visibility.

You do not need to worry about strangers looking away there have been thousands of open sourced projects that started and/or still under a personal account.

**Option 2**

Go ahead and make a GitHub Organization and list the projects there. Depending on your development cycle you may either place them as private or public. And may switch later.

**Option 3**

Make the library on your personal account once it is setup and ready for other contributors you can make a GitHub organization and transfer ownership to that organization.

Don't worry about inactive accounts or not cause I have seen accounts still public without any commits to anything that are still active for more than 4 years.

Comment: thanks for answering. i can't ask another question so i'm just going to do so here. what is the recommended naming convention for repo? e.g. lib-name / app-name / etc or name-lib / name-app / etc?

Comment: for all names, if you have multiple words separate by the minus sign `-`. You should just name the repositories with the name of the library and the name of the app. Cause in the GitHub URL it will push it under either the Organization name or personal account name.

Did that answer your question?

Comment: what if i have a separate repo for the lib and implementation? say the name is Acme. should i name it lib-acme and app-acme or acme-lib and acme-app?

Comment: In that case, it does not matter you can go back and forth with others for years on which way is in some way better. But in the end, it is just a name and since you are the creator you would be the one to decide which one you prefer.